# Unknown error when updating or inserting a record in MS Access database from Classic ASP

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I got a **classic ASP** website to update. I m facing strange problem. Whenever i **insert or update** a record it gives me ***500 (Internal Server) Error***. I deleted old database from the server & uploaded mine database, Could it be the problem ?

The query generated is correct. I copied the query & executed in my database. It worked without any error. But on the server it's not working. Please help me.

When i use `gConn.Execute(str_Qry)` it causes error. Any ideas ?

The file which i am using to connect database is `general.asp`

```
<%
    dim ConnectionString
    ConnectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/Database/MyDB.mdb")        
    '*** Local Connection ***
    'ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=(local)"

    Set gCn = server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
    gCn.Open ConnectionString           
    Set Session("Conn") = gCn   
    Session.Timeout=600 
    Server.ScriptTimeout=2000

    sub closeConnection
        IF gConn.state=adStateOpen Then
            gConn.Close
            set gConn=nothing
            set session("Conn")=""
        End IF
    End sub

    strURL=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
    strjj=split(strURL,"/")
    if ubound(strjj)>1 then
      strPage=strjj(ubound(strjj)) 
    else
      strPage=Mid(strURL,2,Len(strURL)-1)
    end if  
    strPage=LCase(strPage)



    Function IsZilch(v)
        IsZilch = True

        If VarType(v) = 0 Or VarType(v) = 1 Then Exit Function
        If IsNull(v) Then Exit Function
        If (v & "") = "" Then Exit Function

        IsZilch = False
    End Function

    Function SQLFix(s)
        If IsZilch(s) Then SQLFix = "" : Exit Function
        SQLFix = Trim(Replace(s, "'", "''"))
    End Function


    Sub RW(s)
        Response.Write(s)
    End Sub
    Sub RWE(s)
        Response.Write(s)
        Response.End
    End Sub

    Sub RWjs(s)
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>" & s &"</script>")
    End Sub

    Function ConvDate(strDate, strFormat)
    '================================
    'Following are the pattern for date formating
    '   %m Month as a decimal no. 02
    '   %b Abbreviated month name Feb
    '   %B Full month name February
    '   %d Day of the month 23
    '   %j Day of the year 54
    '   %y Year without century 98
    '   %Y Year with century 1998
    '   %w Weekday as integer 5 (0 is Sunday)
    '   %a Abbreviated day name Fri
    '   %A Weekday Name Friday
    '   %I Hour in 12 hour format 12
    '   %H Hour in 24 hour format 24
    '   %M Minute as an integer 01
    '   %S Second as an integer 55
    '   %P AM/PM Indicator PM
    '   %% Actual Percent sign %%   
    '================================
       Dim intPosItem
       Dim intHourPart
       Dim strHourPart
       Dim strMinutePart
       Dim strSecondPart
       Dim strAMPM

       If not IsDate(strDate) Then
          ConvDate = strDate
          Exit Function
       End If

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%m")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          DatePart("m",strDate) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%m")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%b")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          MonthName(DatePart("m",strDate),True) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%b")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%B")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          MonthName(DatePart("m",strDate),False) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%B")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%d")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          DatePart("d",strDate) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%d")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%j")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          DatePart("y",strDate) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%j")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%y")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          Right(DatePart("yyyy",strDate),2) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%y")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%Y")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          DatePart("yyyy",strDate) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%Y")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%w")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          DatePart("w",strDate,1) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%w")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%a")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          WeekDayName(DatePart("w",strDate,1),True) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%a")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%A")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          WeekDayName(DatePart("w",strDate,1),False) & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%A")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%I")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          intHourPart = DatePart("h",strDate) mod 12
          if intHourPart = 0 then intHourPart = 12
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          intHourPart & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%I")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%H")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strHourPart = DatePart("h",strDate)
          if strHourPart < 10 Then strHourPart = "0" & strHourPart
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          strHourPart & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%H")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%M")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strMinutePart = DatePart("n",strDate)
          if strMinutePart < 10 then strMinutePart = "0" & strMinutePart
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          strMinutePart & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%M")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%S")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strSecondPart = DatePart("s",strDate)
          if strSecondPart < 10 then strSecondPart = "0" & strSecondPart
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & _
          strSecondPart & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%S")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%P")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          if DatePart("h",strDate) >= 12 then
             strAMPM = "PM"
          Else
             strAMPM = "AM"
          End If
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & strAMPM & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%P")
       Loop

       intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%%")
       Do While intPosItem > 0
          strFormat = Left(strFormat, intPosItem-1) & "%" & _
          Right(strFormat, Len(strFormat) - (intPosItem + 1))
          intPosItem = Instr(strFormat, "%%")
       Loop

       ConvDate = strFormat

    End Function

    Sub ASPEmailSendMail(sToAddress,sFromAddress,sFromName,sSubject,sBody,sAttachment)
        Dim objAspEmail 
        Set objAspEmail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
        objAspEmail.Host = "localhost"      'Out going SMTP mail server address
        objAspEmail.From = sFromAddress     'Who the e-mail is from

        If sFromName <> "" Then
            objAspEmail.FromName = sFromName 
        End If

        objAspEmail.AddAddress sToAddress   'Who the e-mail is sent to
        objAspEmail.Subject = sSubject      'The subject of the e-mail
        objAspEmail.IsHTML = true
        objAspEmail.Body = sBody            'The main body of the e-mail
        If sAttachment<>"" Then
            'objAspEmail.AddAttachment sAttachment  'Attachment of the e-mail           
        End If

        'Send the e-mail

        If NOT sMailServer = "" Then objAspEmail.Send           
            Set objAspEmail = Nothing
            'ASPEmailSendMail = True
    End Sub

    Sub CDOSendEmail(sName,sEmail,tEmail,sSubject,sHTMLMessage,sAttachment)
        '=============================================================
        '======== These constants can't be modified. =================
        '=============================================================
        Const cdoSendUsingMethod = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
        Const cdoSendUsingPort   = 2
        Const cdoSMTPServer      = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"
        Const cdoSMTPServerPort  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"
        Const cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout"
        Const cdoSMTPAuthenticate       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
        Const cdoBasic                  = 1
        Const cdoAnonymous              = 0
        Const cdoSendUserName           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"
        Const cdoSendPassword           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"

        '==============================================================

        '==============================================================
        '=============== Declare Variables ============================
        '==============================================================
        Dim objConfig  ' As CDO.Configuration
        Dim objMessage ' As CDO.Message
        Dim Fields     ' As ADODB.Fields

        Dim sToName,sToEmail,sHTMLBody,sTextBody

        '===============================================================
        '================= Set object properties for IIS SMTP ==========
        '===============================================================

        Set objConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
        Set Fields = objConfig.Fields

        With Fields
            .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod)       = cdoSendUsingPort
            .Item(cdoSMTPServer)            = "mail.staffavailable.com"
            .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort)        = 25
            .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 10
        '   .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate)      = cdoBasic
            .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate)      = cdoAnonymous
        '   .Item(cdoSendUserName)          = "dbarry@Concierge"
        '   .Item(cdoSendPassword)          = "samson"
            .Update
        End With

        Set objMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig

        sHTMLBody       = "<html><body>" & vbcrlf
        sHTMLBody = sHTMLBody & sHTMLMessage
        sHTMLBody = sHTMLBody & "</body></html>"

        With objMessage
            .To         = tEmail
            .From       = sName & " <" & sEmail & ">"
            .Subject    = sSubject
            .HTMLBody   = sHTMLMessage
            '.TextBody  = sHTMLMessage
            IF sAttachment<>"" Then
                .AddAttachment sAttachment
            End IF
            .Send
        End With

        Set Fields = Nothing
        Set objMessage = Nothing
        Set objConfig = Nothing
    End Sub
%>
```

Comment: You'll need to turn off friendly error messages in IE and make sure IIS is sending detailed error information to the browser to turn that 500 error into something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my comment aside, I'm willing to bet that if the error only started after replacing the database file it's going to be a permission issue and the IUSER account doesn't have write access to the .mdb file.

If you can update your question with a more detailed error message it would help us get you a better answer with less guesswork.

Comment: The problem is that i'm not getting any kind of error messages except 500 - Internal server error !!!!